# Layout within a layout giving me a NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I looked it up on the internet and as far as I can tell it SHOULD work, but then again, the internet always reminds me I am wrong 95% of the time. Anyway, can anyone tell why this ISN'T working? I've gathered it's adding `layoutchild` to `layout` but I don't know why, if it's clearly there? Please and thanks in advance. Sometimes the simplest things give me the most trouble.

Line 24 would be `layout.addView(layoutchild);`

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout layoutchild = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView test = new TextView(this);
    test.setText("pooppoopoppopopo");
    layoutchild.addView(test);
    layout.addView(layoutchild);
}
```

LogKitty:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.eai.util.counter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough, the answer was staring me in the face. I never created an `android:id` and was referencing a layout instead of an ID. In fact, looking back, I used `R.layout`. Should have been blatantly obvious I wasn't gonna get an ID returned. Assigning an ID in XML, *REFERENCING* that ID with the correct `R.id`, and setting the content prior to declaring, fixed and execute perfectly, after a clean.

**CODE:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.pooper);
    LinearLayout layoutchild = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView test = new TextView(this);
    test.setText("DebuggedTheHeckOuttaThis");
    layoutchild.addView(test);
    layout.addView(layoutchild);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exception log shows the exception originated in line 24 of your `MainActivity.java` file on line 24, which is inside your `onCreate` method. You need to tell us which is line 24 of your code.

...but I'm guessing it's one of the lines that's dereferencing whatever `R` or `R.layout` is, or `findViewById` is returning null too.

Add some null checks/assertions in your code or use a step-through debugger to find out what is null and to handle those situations or fix other bugs in your code that cause them to be null.

Comment: Line 24 was marked in my _question_, lemme move some stuff around to make it easier to see.